# STM32H7 timer callback unstable

Tags: stm32

I am working on a project using an STM32H723ZGT6 and using the STM32 HAL. I have previously worked with STM32F4s, where I use the timer callback function `HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback` and `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin` to debug the timers.

However, I experience on the STM32H7 that the timer callback function is behaving erratically. I see the following:

The period generated by `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin` and measured on my oscilloscope does not conform to what I expect. I calculate the period as
$$
\frac{1}{\text{Trigger period}} = \frac{\text{APB1 peripheral clock}}{(\text{PSC} + 1)(\text{ARR} + 1)}
$$
Using the settings `APB1 peripheral clock = 60 MHz`, `PSC = 9` and `ARR = 11` I expect a trigger period of `2 μs`; however, I see a trigger period of `~3.7 μs`. In addition, the output pulses from ´HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback` are unstable/jittery as seen on the oscilloscope.

On the other hand, I drive my DAC via DMA using the same timer, and the output wave from my DAC is very stable *and* running with the expected period for all timer settings... even when the timer is started in interrupt mode using `HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT`. I thus suspect that the timer works as intended, but the problem lies somewhere in the callback function.

Does anyone have a clue as to what could be wrong?

Comment: The STM32H7 HAL's Timer interrupt  handler function `HAL_TIM_IRQHandler`, from which your `HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback` callback is called, is not exactly small - there's a lot of code in there to cover every possible interrupt source from every possible timer in every possible configuration. I think you're being overly optimistic in setting a 2us period and expecting the MCU to be able to execute all that code (as well as whatever else you have going on in your project) within that time period.

Comment: For something timing critical like that you're probably better off writing your own ISR code for that timer which only handles the events you're expecting, and does so as quickly and efficiently as possible, rather than relying on `HAL_TIM_IRQHandler`. There's nothing preventing you from continuing to use the HAL for everything else though, like all the configuration, etc.